# Why am I getting this error \1 not defined in the RE with SED?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to change strings matching this format

`@done(2021-08-13`

to this format

`#done/2021/08/13`

using this regex: `'s|\@done.([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)|#done/\1/\2/\3|'`

and I am receiving this error: \1 not defined in the RE

Hoping for some help from the masters.

Comment: The `(...)` need to be escaped in sed `\(...\)`.

Comment: Or, use `-E` to make it POSIX ERE compliant. You also use `+` that is treated as a literal char in POSIX BRE.

Comment: Thanks! Much Appreciated.